# Systemctl cannot run Script command on openvpn

Tags: openvpn, systemd, systemctl

It is weird that the /usr/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service is a simple task:

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenVPN Robust And Highly Flexible Tunneling Application On %I
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=notify
PrivateTmp=true
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --cd /etc/openvpn/ --config %i.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However, when I tried to make a self-start openvpn script like `autoinit.service` with 
`ExecStart=/bin/bash /root/setvpn.sh`

Where as `/root/setvpn.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/sbin/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/tun0.conf
```

Then this indirect start encounters a mistake：

```
# systemctl start autoinit
Warning: autoinit.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
# systemctl status autoinit
● autoinit.service - Sets up OpenVPN servers
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/autoinit.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: deactivating (stop-sigterm) since Fri 2020-05-15 18:54:50 CST; 12s ago
  Process: 10692 ExecStart=/root/setvpn.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 10692 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/autoinit.service
           └─10694 /usr/sbin/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/tun0.conf
```

Actually if I run `systemctl daemon-reload` before start this autoinit service, it will halt and cannot start at all.
Of course `/root/setvpn.sh` has no problem of execution, why is that systemctl cannot run it?

Comment: long story short: `systemctl -> openvpn` OK ; `systemctl->bash->openvpn` Error

Comment: Ownership and file mode (of the script) is missing as information that could be relevant here.

Comment: by root: `-rw-r--r-x` then I changed it to `-rwxr--r-x` still won't work

Comment: for a simplistic openvpn start just `openvpn --daemon --dev tun --ifconfig 10.100.0.1 10.100.0.2`